# My JQuery Ajax call gives error: EXPECTED POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I get an 'EXPECTED POST' error in my console when I click the button. `console.log(data)`  is highlighted yellow. Presumably there is a JSON problem, but I could not find it.

```js
var success_callback = function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  $('#results')[0].innerHTML = data;
}

$('button').click(function() {
  $.ajax('ajax.php', {
    data: {
      submission: JSON.stringify({
        prop: $('text_area').val()
      })
    },
    success: success_callback
  });
});
```

Comment: Voting to close since the issue is _caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the server side endpoint is expecting a POST request, yet you're sending a GET (as that's the jQuery `$.ajax` default). To fix this just add `type: 'POST'` to the settings.

Also note that you can use jQuery's `html()` method instead of creating a jQuery object, getting an Element from it then updating the `innerHTML`. Try this:

```js
var success_callback = function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  $('#results').html(data);
}

$('button').click(function() {
  $.ajax('ajax.php', {
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      submission: JSON.stringify({
        prop: $('text_area').val()
      })
    },
    success: success_callback
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Rory. I put the above-given code and replaced mine. It gives the same "unexpected token error '<' highlighted with <html><head><title>BetterHelp Challenge</title>. What can we do?

Comment: That error means that the `ajax.php` page is returning HTML instead of JSON. You need to debug why that is happening.