# How to add post type from console... Error: Expected POST console html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

[My JQuery Ajax call gives error: EXPECTED POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60926453/my-jquery-ajax-call-gives-error-expected-post)

I am having the same issue as the guy in the link. I need to post instead of get, but I cannot change the ajax code directly. I have to do it from the console dynamically using JavaScript

I have been making changes in the index.html file via the console. Here is part of the index.html file:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>For some reason, this form is submitted via AJAX, but there are a couple of bugs preventing that from working. Use your browser's console to fix it.</p>
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Form is broken, see Step 2');">Submit</button>

<h3>Results:</h3>
<div id='results'>
</div>
<script>
var success_callback = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#results')[0].innerHTML = data;
}
$('button').click(function(){
    $.ajax('ajax.php', {
                        data: {submission: JSON.stringify({prop: $('text_area').val()})},
                        success: success_callback
                       }
    );
});
</script>
```

I know all I have to do is add `type: 'POST',` right before data. If I could change the index.html file directly, I would. but I can't, so how can I do this using JavaScript during runtime from this
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcarj.png)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please don't put output in an image. it sucks for copy pasting. thanks :)

Comment: Why can't you download the HTML and JS files? Just click "save as" in the browser. Or right-click the JS file in the inspector to get the direct URL.

Comment: @Kokodoko Yeah! The challenge is to see who's the first to get someone on Stack Overflow to fix the problem for them! ;)

Comment: @HereticMonkey i know what i have to do but i have never used ajax jquery before this. i tried to figure out how to do it, but couldnt find anything, so i made my own post:)

Comment: But it's not about jQuery or AJAX, it's about the right mindset how to approach the problem in general. You need to learn how to ask yourself the right questions. In this case, how can I modify what code runs there eventually? Can I somehow replace part of the code or insert my own? Unrelated to any library functions that you may know or not know. See my post for two solutions, but please don't just submit them and be happy but instead try understanding what they mean and how you could arrive at these ideas yourself - it's an universal way of thinking and problem-solving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the click listener and add your own with the modified code:

```js
$('button').off('click').click(() => {
  $.ajax('ajax.php', {
    data: { submission: JSON.stringify({ prop: $('text_area').val() }) },
    success: success_callback,
    type: 'POST'
  })
})
```

Since `success_callback` is defined in the global scope, it should be callable by your code too.

---

Another option would be to monkey-patch `$.ajax`.

Very dirty, but it will do the job too... Something like this:

```js
const oldAjax = $.ajax
$.ajax = function (url, opts) {
  if (url !== 'ajax.php') return oldAjax.apply(this, arguments)
  return oldAjax.call(this, url, { ...opts, type: 'POST' })
}
```

This will replace `$.ajax` by your own function which will then either just call the original function with unmodified arguments if `url` isn't `ajax.php` , or, if it *is* `ajax.php`, insert `type: 'POST'` into the options object.

See also: https://www.audero.it/blog/2016/12/05/monkey-patching-javascript/#using-monkey-patching-to-change-a-method

(Note: This is not the method of choice in normal circumstances!)

Comment: thank you very much! i read the link. I made some progress and am still stuck. can you help me? I made a post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66896217/submission-empty-or-json-decode-of-submission-failed-how-to-submit-textarea-ins