# Submission empty or json decode of submission failed. how to submit textarea inside form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<p><h3>Enter your SQL query below:</h3>
<form method="post" action="http://212.47.247.139/challenge/ajax.php?submission=%7B%7D" id="my-form">
    <textarea id='text1' class='sql' name='submission' rows=10 cols=120></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="blogSubmit" onclick="getText()">
    <br>
</form>
</p>
<script>
    function getText() {
        // var str=document.getElementById("text1").value;
        // alert(str + "i did it");

        $.ajax('ajax.php?submission=%7B%7D', {
                    data: {submission: $('#text1').val()},
                    success: function(data) {
                        success_callback(data);
                        console.log("success " + data);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        alert(error);
                    },
                    type: 'POST'
                })
    }
</script>
```

I have a text area inside a form that holds some sql statement. I have a submit button inside the form. What i want to have happen is: when the user clicks the submit button, whatever is inside the textarea gets POSTED to "http://212.47.247.139/challenge/ajax.php?submission=%7B%7D" using ajax.

After submitting, When I look under the network tab, i see the form data has what I enter in, but I get a "Submission empty or json decode of submission failed". I am new to ajax, html, and javascript. In place of the `$('#blogSubmit').val()`, I have tried many things such as `JSON.stringify({ prop: $('#blogSubmit').val()`

What i am doing wrong?

UPDATE after implementing changes Barmer suggested

```
   <p><h3>Enter your SQL query below:</h3>
    <form method="post" action="http://212.47.247.139/challenge/ajax.php?submission=%7B%7D" id="my-form">
        <textarea id='text1' class='sql' name='submission' rows=10 cols=120></textarea>
        <input type="button" id="blogSubmit" onclick="getText()">
        <br>
    </form>
    </p>
    <script>
        function getText() {
            // var str=document.getElementById("text1").value;
            // alert(str + "i did it");
    
            $.ajax('ajax.php?submission=%7B%7D', {
                        data: {submission: { prop: JSON.stringify($("#text1").val())}},
                        success: function(data) {
                            success_callback(data);
                            console.log("success " + data);
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                            alert(error);
                        },
                        type: 'POST'
                    })
        }
</script>
```

Now I get this error: "**Warning**:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in **/var/www/my_website/challenge/ajax.php** on line **31**
Submission empty or json decode of submission failed"

Why would it say an array is given when I am doing JSON.stringify to convert it to string?

Comment: You're not sending `$("#text1").val()` in the AJAX request.

Comment: `#blogSubmit` should be `#text1`.

Comment: You also need to prevent the default form submission. You're sending twice: Once via AJAX, and then via normal submission.

Comment: The error message also implies that it expects the parameter to be in JSON format, but `$.ajax` sends URL-encoded format.

Comment: @Barmar thank you sir. Addressing your third comment, i want the ajax submission right? How do I prevent default form submission and use the ajax one

Comment: You can change the input to `type="button"` instead of a submit button.

Comment: If it's supposed to be JSON, use `submission: JSON.stringify($("#text1").val())`

Comment: No json involved in the POST either. Default $.ajax is sending form encoded data.... the same as a regular form does

Comment: Then why would it say "json decode of submission failed" if it didn't expect it to be JSON?

Comment: @Barmar i made all the edits you suggested, thanks again! now im getting "Missing or empty submission prop in json". I got this error before

Comment: `getText` should be run `onsubmit` of the `<form>`, not the submit button... and you need to pass in `event` and `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @Barmar i changed it to "submission: { prop: JSON.stringify($("#text1").val())}".  Now it says "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string. Submission empty or json decode of submission failed"

Comment: I need to see the documentation of the API you're submitting to. Otherwise I'm just guessing what kind of data it expects.

Comment: Why did you change the name from `submission:` to `prop:`?

Comment: it is still submission. i just added a prop since i got an error message saying "Missing or empty submission prop in json"

Answer (score 1):

Change the submit button to `type="button"` so it doesn't submit the form, it just runs your function.

In the AJAX call, convert the value of the textarea to JSON with `JSON.stringify()`.

```js
function getText() {

  $.ajax('ajax.php?submission=%7B%7D', {
    data: {
      submission: JSON.stringify($('#text1').val())
    },
    success: function(data) {
      success_callback(data);
      console.log("success " + data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      alert(error);
    },
    type: 'POST'
  })
}
```

```html
<p>
  <h3>Enter your SQL query below:</h3>
  <form method="post" action="http://212.47.247.139/challenge/ajax.php?submission=%7B%7D" id="my-form">
    <textarea id='text1' class='sql' name='submission' rows=10 cols=120></textarea>
    <input type="button" id="blogSubmit" onclick="getText()">
    <br>
  </form>
</p>
```

Comment: Better to run `onsubmit` of the `<form>` and `event.preventDefault()`. Some Browsers submit when you hit Enter.

Comment: @StackSlave They only do that if there's a submit button.